# Observable zip order

Tags: android, rx-java

I got 3 observable objects

```
Observable<CharSequence> o1 = RxTextView.textChanges(quitBuddyName);
Observable<CharSequence> o2 = RxTextView.textChanges(quitBuddyPhone);
Observable<CircleInviteListAdapter> o3 = RxAdapter.dataChanges(listAdapter);

Observable.zip(o1, o2, o3, (a, b, c) -> {    
     return a.length() > 0 && b.length() > 0 && c != null;
}).subscribe(finishBtn::setEnabled);
```

Question: Why finish button is not enabled after I set adapter first then enter text?

Answer (score 1):

You're after `combineLatest`, not `zip`.

Zip needs results from *all* sources to produce a new one.

CombineLatest triggers after a change in *either* of the sources, but only after all 3 sources have produced at least one value.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure from the code but here are 2 guesses.

1 - An error occurs. You're not doing anything `onError` so if an error occurs you're never going to know about it.

2 - Your Observable isn't emitting anything. Again, as you're not performing an `Action` `onComplete` you won't know if your Observable completes without emitting.

As noted in the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

> It will only emit as many items as the number of items emitted by the
>   source Observable that emits the fewest items

So if one of your source `Observables` completes without emitting, then your zip doesn't do anything and your `Subscribe` just calls `onComplete`

In general, I would always recommend implementing at least `onNext` & `onError`, and usually I implement `onComplete`, even if it's to just log something at `debug` level.